# Uneven grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float

Here is the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/wnud4/1/

I'm wanting all of the green boxes and blue boxes to fall into order one after the other with no large gaps, aside from the established margins. For some reason, the second element in the blue column is complaining about alignment. Does anyone have any suggestions, or could provide guidance if I am approaching this the wrong way. I don't want to predefine columns, but other than that I'm open to anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using floats on both columns, you could only use `float: left` on the left column, and simply use `margin-left` on the right column, to push those divs past the floated divs. Then you'd just need to clean up your widths and margins to keep everything even.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/UZY6t/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help, that should work just like I was hoping!

Answer (score 0):

Untested in anything except Google Chrome and FF but you could try using a combination of float: left and margin-left:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnud4/7/