# When adding a photo to a grid, it changes the layout of another element - how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm very very new to CSS so just playing around and learning new things. I created a somewhat messy grid and I tried adding a photo into one of my div's, but for some reason when I add and resize it, it completely changes the spacing of the elements on the right side of the page (the template blog posts.) When I remove the image from my HTML it goes back to normal. I'm sorry if my code is terrible I'm still new, just wanted to play around with this type of formatting. Here is my HTML and CSS.

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr;
}

.blog {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column: 3;
  width: 80%;
  gap: inherit;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(79 185 227);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 400px;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sidebar p {
  font-family: Monospace, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sidebar img {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50;
  font-size: 120%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #8a5f88;
  height: 50px;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Monospace, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 13px 29px;
  font-size: 140%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #e7b4ed;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 230%;
}

footer {
  background-color: #8a5f88;
  color: white;
  font-family: Monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p class="title">will have header here with the blog title</p>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="alarry.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  </nav>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Welcome to the Blog!</h2>
    <p>I can introduce myself here. It will be one of the first things people see when they enter the website. I can have a photo of myself and a short description, and possibly links to my socials as well.</p><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="ren" alt="Fireworks at the Faire"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="blog">
    <h2>Example Blog Title</h2>
    <p> This would begin the body of the blog post. Here I can insert photos, use headings, and write to make a blog post. I'll just have to style and position it all a certain way.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="blog">
    <h2>Second Blog Post Example</h2>
    <p>I would keep a pretty standard form and make the page simply scrollable for a while (then eventually figure out how to make more pages if I write more).</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blog">
    <h2>Another Blog Post</h2>
    <p>And that's pretty much it, I want to start very simple and just focus on making the blog posts simple, well styled, and easy to read.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Copyright @2023 Julia Bruns</p>
</footer>
```

I tried to make sure I wasn't adding my img into the wrong div, and somehow having its attributes also apply to my .blog div. I tried out writing my grid attributes differently, because I'm still learning those methods and different ways to do it, but I can't figure out why having the img in the .sidebar is affecting the .blog. I thought it might be the .container but I can't figure out what that might be, or what I need to add to it to change it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: On your .comtainer div, you've said 'grid-template-columns: 3fr' but you've not stated how many columns you want? This will just create columns as it sees fit.  As you've set grid-column to be 3 on .blog, it's creating a 3 column grid. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/50700360/1741542; I searched for "css uneven grid".

Comment: Here is another one, which might fit https://stackoverflow.com/q/8578962/1741542

Comment: Hello @Adam, I see what you pointed out. I think I initially chose '3' because I wanted the column to be further to the right... that was silly haha. I changed it to 2 because I can shape the column how I want. The issue is that, when I had an img in to the sidebar div, for some reason it affects the .blog div and cause the first 'blog post' to stretch longer with a lot of empty space in it. When I take the photo out, it goes back to normal. Is there something in my code that is connecting them accidentally? Thank you for your kind reply!